# search for info in a table in a database when button pressed

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to search for a table. When I search for a name in the column name men when I run the program and fx search for babar in the searchbox the programs says the the column name doesn't exist

```
try {     
    //        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/BOBSHOP";
            String Username = "babar";`enter code here`
            String Password = "babar";
            String DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, Username, Password);

            //String sql = "Select * FROM \"Kundetabel\" WHERE navn =?";
            //String sql = "select * from BABAR.\"Kundetabel\" WHERE navn=?";
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM \"Kundetabel\" WHERE navn LIKE '%navn%'";

            pst = con2.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,sogeTextField1.getText());

            String sognavn = sogeTextField1.getText();

            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
            String add1=rs.getString("kundeID");
            sogedisplayTextField1.setText(add1);
            String add2=rs.getString("navn");
            sogedisplayTextField2.setText(add2);
            String add3=rs.getString("efternavn");
            sogedisplayTextField3.setText(add3);
            String add4=rs.getString("adresse");
            sogedisplayTextField4.setText(add4);
            String add5=rs.getString("email");
            sogedisplayTextField5.setText(add5);
            String add6=rs.getString("telefonnr");
            sogedisplayTextField6.setText(add6);
            String add7=rs.getString("kode");
            sogedisplayTextField7.setText(add7);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HardwareStore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?

Comment: It says that the colomn name doesnt exist men i't does!

Comment: as you can see, i have tried a lots of differens sentences

Comment: I'm more inclined to believe the program. It's your `rs.getString()` that are failing.

Comment: Post your exception.  Print out your SQL statement and run it directly against the database.

Comment: andrew - what you mean ? can i please explain how to